# System.OutOfMemoryException in System.Drawing.dll while hovering chart if stepline selected as ChartType and annotations in use

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, out-of-memory, system.drawing

Why on earth this very simple c# code with two series is throwing OutOfMemory exception from System.Drawing.dll when chart is mouse hovered?

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

            Series serieA = new Series();
            serieA.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine; // If commented, problem doesn't exist
            serieA.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 4.5));
            serieA.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6.5, 5.5));


            Series serieAnnotation = new Series();
            serieAnnotation.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine;
            serieAnnotation.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 4.5));
            serieAnnotation.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 5.5));


            TextAnnotation annotation = new TextAnnotation()
            {
                Text = "A",
                AnchorDataPoint = serieAnnotation.Points[0],
            };

            this.chart.Annotations.Add(annotation); // If commented, problem doesn't exist

            this.chart.Series.Add(serieA);
            this.chart.Series.Add(serieAnnotation);
        }
    }
```

InitializeComponent() is boilerplate code created automatically by Visual Studio.

Stack trace for proplem:

```
    System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.Widen(System.Drawing.Pen pen, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix matrix, float flatness)  Unknown
    System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.Widen(System.Drawing.Pen pen)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartTypes.StepLineChart.DrawLine(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartGraphics graph, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CommonElements common, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series, System.Drawing.PointF[] points, int pointIndex, float tension) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartTypes.LineChart.ProcessChartType(bool selection, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartGraphics graph, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CommonElements common, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea area, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesToDraw)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartTypes.LineChart.Paint(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartGraphics graph, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CommonElements common, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea area, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesToDraw)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.Paint(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartGraphics graph) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graph, bool paintTopLevelElementOnly) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.PaintOffScreen()    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Selection.HitTest(int x, int y, bool ignoreTransparent, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType[] requestedElementTypes)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Selection.HitTest(int x, int y, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType requestedElement)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.HitTest(int x, int y, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType requestedElement)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AnnotationCollection.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnChartMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown
>   TestApp.exe!TestApp.Program.Main() Line 19  C#
```

I would like to highlight that exception is thrown when chart is hovered.

What makes the situation even more weird for me is that exception doesn't occur anymore if either ChatyType of serieA or annotation adding is commented out from the code.

Comment: I tried your code, but I did not get any exception. Probably there is another piece of code that cause this problem. Obs: .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization You should also notice that Microsoft didn't want to keep it any more (and originally it was purchased from Dundas Charts). You should consider other commercial or open source alternatives if you want solutions.

Comment: Thank you @D.Kastier for giving a try for code. The presented code is all I have beside of basic definitions done automatically by VS. However I'm using 4.7.2.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi pointing this out. New information for me and forces me to think should we use WinForm DataVisualization at all in our project.

Comment: Maybe it is a Windows thing... [Check this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-outofmemoryexception-exception-when-you-use-a-graphics-object-to-paint-in-a-net-framework-3-5-based-windows-forms-application-fd2c4d42-6137-a793-a17f-3e8f2cf46fb7). Also, @LexLi's idea sounds the the best solution.